# Can I Join 3 table using Natural Join?

Tags: relational-algebra

The image down below shows a small database,
[image]

I got a question

> Give a relational algebra expression to find the name of the judge who
>   presides over the trial for defendant known as “Mike” starting on
>   1.12.2012.

And the answer given is

[image]

---

But I think it should Join `JUDGE` table as well something like this :

Please leave some comment if I' wrong about this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you don't need to join the `JUDGE` table to get the judge's name.

Notice how `Jname` is the primary key of `JUDGE`s, that is to say, a judge is uniquely identified by her name; and the `TRIAL` table will actually contain `Jname` denoting which judge presided over a given trial:

```
Judge | Defendant | Number | Sdate
Dredd |  1        |   1    | 1.12.2012
Dredd |  2        |   2    | 2.12.2012
Rico  |  1        |   3    | 1.12.2012
```

You can see how selecting tuples yields us the judge's name without joining anything in. (In case you're wondering, this is a very bad design that you should never employ in the real world.)

In contrast, we do have to join `DEFENDANT` with `TRIAL`: a `DEFENDANT`'s primary key is his ID, so only that ID appears in the `TRIAL` table, so if we need to select a defendant by name, we have to employ a join.

As for your question title: yes, you can of course join more than three tables. If you find it hard to imagine, recall that `R ⨝ S ⨝ T = (R ⨝ S) ⨝ T`. Note that natural join is nicely commutative and associative as well.