# Use two different relational algebra to do a query

Tags: relational-algebra

Here is the relation schema:

```
MANUFACTURER (Name, Country, Contact_Person, Phone)
CAR (Plates, Manufacturer, Model, Year, Class)
MAINTENANCE (RepairNo, Car, RepairDate, Procedure, Mileage, TotalTime) CUSTOMER (CustNo, Name, Address, Phone)
RENTAL (Car, Customer, StartDate, ReturnDate, Cost)
```

I want to use 2 different relational algebra to query that show all car models produced by manufacturers from Italy,

The 2 solutions that I came up with are

[image]

And

[image]

Please let me know if I'm wrong about this

Comment: seems fine to me. The second should be more efficient if deployed into a system

Comment: @amit Thanks for your quick reply. I'm new to this area, could you come up a different solution?

Comment: @amit BTW could you have a look my another related question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19740069/456218

Comment: If you use your second approach and instead of CAR and MANUFACTURER add the tables `Pi_Name,Country(MANUFACTURER)` and `Pi_Model,Manufacturer(CAR)` - it is most likely to achieve even better performance.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went wrong (or right). See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted.